# Search word in text file and print the line

Tags: java, text-files

How can i search certain text in a text file and then print the line that contains it?

i already was using tries, here's my code:

```
Collection<Emit> emits = t.parseText("text to look in");
String results = "Found lines: ";
for (Emit e : emits) {
    results += "\r\nWord: "+e.getKeyword();
}
System.out.println(results);
try {
    sendEmail(results);
} catch (AddressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can i change the code or what approach should i take? I am using the code to monitor the apache logs every half hour looking for HTTP request that may contain SQL injection.

thank you in advance